# Can I save a sketch in a different resolution than the size in processing?

Tags: processing

I need to print one of my sketches and for it I need to save it on a big resolution. At least `5000px x 5000px`. The thing is that I can not run my sketch with that size. Is there any way I can save a frame in a different resolution than the sketch `size()`

In order to save I am using:

```
void mousePressed(){
  save("myfile-"+hour()+""+minute()+""+second()+".tif");
}
```

Any tip will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You're only saving one image per second?

Comment: Yes, I just need one image which I will use for a print. The idea is that when I click the sketch it will save it with a big resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**: Just save them like you're doing now, and then scale them afterwards, outside of Processing. You can do this in Windows just by right-clicking and going to "Resize pictures", or you can use something like [ImageMagic](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php). This has the benefit of not having to change your sketch at all, and you'll probably be able to use better scaling algorithms to eliminate ugly resizing artifacts.

**Option 2**: Create a `PImage` the same size as the screen. Then set the pixels of that `PImage` to the screen's pixels. You can then scale that image up and save it. It might look something like this:

```
void setup(){
  size(100, 100);
}

void draw(){
  background(0);
  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 20, 20);
}

void mousePressed(){
 PImage img = createImage(100, 100, RGB);
 img.set(0, 0, get());
 img.resize(1000, 1000);
 img.save("myfile-"+hour()+""+minute()+""+second()+".tif");
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I went for your second option as sometimes ImageMagic can be a little imprecise when converting files to vectors. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I recommend having a look [Processing's pdf library](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/pdf/) and it's examples (Processing > Examples > Libraries > pdf).
Bellow is the basic Mouse Press example it ships with, slightly tweaked to resize to 5000x5000.

```
/**
 * Mouse Press. 
 * 
 * Saves one PDF of the contents of the display window 
 * each time the mouse is pressed.
 */


    import processing.pdf.*;

    boolean saveOneFrame = false;

    void setup() {
      size(500, 500);
      frameRate(24);
    }

    void draw() {
      if(saveOneFrame == true) {
        size(5000,5000);
        beginRecord(PDF, "Line.pdf"); 
      }

      background(255);
      stroke(0, 20);
      strokeWeight(20.0);
      line(mouseX, 0, width-mouseY, height);

      if(saveOneFrame == true) {
        endRecord();
        saveOneFrame = false;
        size(500,500); 
      }
    }

    void mousePressed() {
      saveOneFrame = true; 
    }
```

If you're saving every once in a while, this should work.
A vector PDF should be better for print than a scaled up raster image.
Even if you save the PDF file at 500x500, in vector format you can scale up without any quality loss.

If for some reason you need to save really large prints and run your program as fast as possible, this will be a bit more complicated, but not impossible.
You can serialise each draw command to a file in a separate thread (so the animation thread doesn't stutter). This file can than be read in a separate program that simple reads every single instruction and renders it to a large scale pdf. You can see this concept in practice with the [Engine26](http://engine26.net/) digital painting system:

[image: Engine26]

Comment: Thanks a lot George. I will test this solution again, as I remember trying it while I was researching but never managed to get the same quality in the pdf as what I was seeing. I will try your code and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: No worries, let me know how you get on. I'm guessing you're using mostly drawing commands and not using pixels, right ?

Comment: Yes, actually, similar to the example you posted. I am transforming a JPG into drawings. Like this sketch http://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/117624 Thanks again.

Comment: That shouldn't be a massive problem, because the example code you linked to is simply sampling the brightness of pixels and the particles move independently, so the draw instructions can be rendered at high res (event if the image isn't)...just the coordinates need to be scaled (using ```scale()``` when rendering the pdf large might just do the job without too much hassle)

Comment: Hello George. I was finally able to test the code and Processing is complaining about adding size() inside draw(). Do you have any idea how to circumvent this? Again, thank you!

Comment: Nevermind my last comment. I found out that if I remove the size() I can then change the size directly on Photoshop so no problem. Wha I am seeing are some outlines and lines that are not on my original sketch. Do you also get this? Thanks

Comment: re: outlines - strange if they don't show up in the sketch. any way you can post the code for testing ? (hopefully just some stray line styles somewhere ?)

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I really appreciate it. I think that for some reason the PDF generator `sees` the triangles even though they are with `alpha=0`. Here is the example code where I tested your code http://pastebin.com/aQQTYAW9. When I save it I get a black line around all triangles, even the ones that are not there. In the worst case I can delete it with illustrator, I just wanted to understand what is going on. Thanks a lot

Comment: Nice composition! I see what the issue is: the PDF renderer hasn't picked up you set ```noStroke()``` in ```setup()```. However you can explicitly tell the PDF renderer to use no stroke. Simply replace the ```beginRecord()``` line with these two:```PGraphicsPDF pdf = (PGraphicsPDF)beginRecord(PDF, "Triangles.pdf");
        pdf.noStroke();```.

Comment: Thanks!!!! still learning as you see. Thanks a lot for all your help, I really appreciate it.